# Randomly check a radio button after a certain time

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I randomly check a new radio button after a certain time?

I like to archive the effect that the checked radio button automaticially change  every 5 seconds. Thank you!

```
<input type="radio" id="mc" name="radiobutton" value="Mastercard" checked>
<label for="mc"> Mastercard</label><br> 
<input type="radio" id="vi" name="radiobutton" value="Visa">
<label for="vi">  Visa</label><br> 
<input type="radio" id="ae" name="radiobutton" value="AmericanExpress">
<label for="ae"> American Express</label>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `setInterval`

```js
var $inputs = $("input[type=radio]");
setInterval(function() {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * $inputs.length);
  $inputs.each(function(i, node) {
    node.checked = (i === random);
  });
}, 5000); // 5000 = 5 seconds
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="mc" name="radiobutton" value="Mastercard" checked>
<label for="mc">Mastercard</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" id="vi" name="radiobutton" value="Visa">
<label for="vi">Visa</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" id="ae" name="radiobutton" value="AmericanExpress">
<label for="ae">American Express</label>
```

Comment: Great! it worked for me, it will be more good if snippet added for jquery also.